# R: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x' not found

Tags: r

I am quite new to R, so this might seem like a really simple question. However I don't know specifically what to search for because I don't really know what is causing the problem. Both CSV-files mentioned below are formatted in the same way, which is the reason I don't know what is causing the trouble. However the CSV that is returning the error mentioned below has many more rows than the other.

I have a certain dataset I want to run a linear model on (lm in R). I imported it into R from a CSV using this code in R:

> rawData=read.csv("dataset.csv", header=T)

When requesting an output of the ten top rows by we get:

```
> head(rawData, 10)
   ï..x   y
1     1 0.0
2     2 0.0
3     3 0.0
4     4 0.0
5     5 0.0
6     6 0.5
7     7 0.0
8     8 0.0
9     9 0.1
10   10 0.0
```

From the above output we see that the top row display as follows:

```
ï..x   y
```

Running a linear model on the last one returns an error messages:

```
simple.fit = lm(x~y, data=dataset)
summary(simple.fit)
```

The error message returned is:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x' not found
```

How can this be solved?

As we can see below the output from an import of another CSV file (I just used  for testing linear regression) in R the output is as follows:

```
> rawData=read.csv("testing.csv", header=T)
> head(rawData, 10)
             x          y
1  82.58321982 134.907414
2  73.92246618 134.085180
3  34.88744536         NA
4  61.83998269 114.530638
5  16.77594025  31.376437
6   0.01673734   8.764634
7  44.45764646  73.285341
8  10.34490930  18.859865
9  42.76713229  72.946609
10 20.85663802  28.637286
```

Here we see the top row have simply:

```
x          y
```

Running a linear model on the last one returns no error messages and gives an output
    simple.fit = lm(x~y, data=testing)
    summary(simple.fit)

Comment: `names(rawData) <- c("x", "y")` ... just readjust the names if `read.csv` is not giving you names which are easy to use.  This seems like a typo error to me.

Comment: With that usggestion it worked out now. Maybe the problem had to do with encoding of the CSV files. Perhaps one was encoded with UTF8, while the other with something else.

Comment: Could be that...in any case you might often find yourself changing the names of the CSV columns.  It's a useful thing to put in a bag of tricks.

Answer (score 1):

For such situations, you can try using `clean_names()` from the library `janitor`.